# Retrieve all edges of a community in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

How can I get all edges of a community in igraph?

```
g <- graph.edgelist(edges, directed=FALSE)
c <- edge.betweenness.community(g)
listOfCommunities <- communities(c)
```

`listOfCommunities` stores lists of verteces for each community. I would like to get all the edges for each community.

Comment: It seems this can be retrieved using `E(g)[from(x)]` where x is a vector of verteces (e.g. `x <- listOfCommunities[[1]]`). `from` being used because this is an undirected graph.

Comment: Please consider supplying a reproducible example, it increases the chance of getting an answer. As for your question try `E(g)[ listOfCommunities[[1]] %--% listOfCommunities[[1]] ]`, etc.